# Apache won't start, MySql and FileZilla does

Tags: apache-2.2, php, xampp, windows-7

I am using Windows7 and XAMPP 1.7.3(it's 32bit but says it works on 64). When I click on start Apache nothing happens but beneath it is written:

"Busy.... Apache Service started"

But the green running text does not appear

Port 80 in Skype is disabled. I do not have IIS on my computer.

When I tried to start the Apache 2.2 service from the control panel, it throws an alert box stating it's a service specific error code 1.

Someone said change Listen 80 to 85 in the httpd.conf file. This didn't work. When I tried to start the Apache 2.2 service from the control panel, it throws an alert box stating it's a service specific error code 1.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the event viewer?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Error Viewer message below.

The Apache2.2 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..

Similar to the alert box 'error code 1'

Comment: and this in error log
Syntax error on line 505 of C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
SSLSessionCache: Invalid argument: size has to be >= 8192 bytes

checking config now ...

 line 505
<IfModule ssl_module>
   SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
   SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
   SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
   SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 64. I did install XAMPP to the 'program files' folder though. I thought I had set the permissions correctly for the xampp foldder afterwards but Apache would not start. To be certain that this was not related to the install being in the 'program files' directory I heeded the advice given above and reinstalled to c:\xampp. That did it. For me XAMPP worked when installed outside of the 'program files' dir.

Comment: Thanks I will try this in the future as this seems to be the solution for XAMPP on Windows 7. I'm sticking with my XP laptop for now. Strange, I can't recall seeing any mention of this on the XAMPP website or installation documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping into command line and manually run xampp_stop.exe, and then run xampp_start.exe and see what it tells you.  I have had mine act a little quirky in the past and looking at the command output will typically lead me in the right direction.

Windows 7 has acted a little strange for me when I have it installed as a service.  I have had to disable service and just start it manually (albeit through the console) each time I boot into my OS.

This should report any Virtual Host problems, log files missing, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No message comes up on screen when using cmd line. It simply appears then disappears for xampp_stop and with xampp_start it just says xampp starting ... then closes

Comment: You might have a bum installation.  I would remove your current install, reboot the machine, and reinstall.  Also, be sure to install it outside of the 'program files' directory since Vista and 7 put extra permissions on that folder.  I usually set mine up in c:\xampp\.  Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try this in the future as this seems to be the solution for XAMPP on Windows 7. I'm sticking with my XP laptop for now. Strange, I can't recall seeing any mention of this on the XAMPP website or installation documents.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem: (on Win XP)

When I installed wamp, `C:` was not my root drive - my main drive was `E:`. Even though I changed the installation path to be `E:\wamp` I figured that some files in the `E:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra` directory have hard coded paths on `C:`. Just replace them with the appropriate path on your installation drive. Check the `httpd-autoindex`, `httpd-dav`, `httpd-multilang-errordoc`, `httpd-ssl`, `httpd-vhosts`.

Then restart the apache service.

I hope this will help you.